# use react hook form with custom TextInput

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I'm trying to use react hook form with custom TextInput. Before I was using materials input and everything was working correctly. A found one way that I can achieve it but I'm not satisfied with that.

I'm using `useForm` hook

```
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors, isValid },
  } = useForm<FormValues>({ resolver: yupResolver(schema), mode: "all" });
```

And my custom TextField (pretty simple because for now I want just to register it into form):

```
export interface TextFieldProps {
    id: string;
    error: string | undefined;
    label: string;
    register: UseFormRegister<any>
}

const TextField = ({ id, error, label, register }: TextFieldProps): JSX.Element => {
    return <>
    <input {...register(`${id}`)}></input>
    {error}
    </>
  };
```

using that component:

```
          <TextField
            register={register}
            id="username"
            label="Username"
            error={errors.username?.message}
          />
```

This code is working but I'm losing IMO very nice feature - checking the name that I passed to register function. For example I have some schema declared:

```
  const schema = yup.object({
    username: yup.string().required("Username is required"),
    password: yup.string().required("Password is required"),
  });
```

And If I try the code below. Typescript will say me that I don't have email field in my schema.

```
          <input
          {...register("email")}>
          </input>
```

I'm still trying to modify TextInput component to be able to use it like:

```
          <TextField
            {...register("username")}
            id="username"
            label="Username"
            error={errors.username?.message}
          />
```

but I'm still facing with warning `Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?`
How should that TextField component look to avoid that forwardRef warning?

Comment: Why not pass `UseFormRegisterReturn` instead of `UseFormRegister`? This lets you call `register` from the outside and you get the type-safety.

Comment: You don't need to pass `register` at all - it's passed in `ref`. See answer by @Joris. Should be accepted - works as a charm

Answer (score 6):

You've to pass the `ref` and below is one of the ways to achieve that

```
export interface TextFieldProps extends React.PropsWithoutRef<JSX.IntrinsicElements["input"]> {
    error: string | undefined;
    label: string;
}

const TextField = forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, LabeledTextFieldProps>({ errorm label, ...props }, ref) => {
    return (
      <>
        <input {...props} ref={ref}></input>
        {error}
      </>
    )
  });
```

You're to be able to use it like:

```
<TextField {...register('username')} label="Username label" error={formState.errors.username.message}/>
```

Comment: Missing an open bracket on the forwardRef, should be: `... LabeledTextFieldProps>(({ ...`

Comment: Why not pass `UseFormRegisterReturn` instead of `UseFormRegister`? This allows you to call `register` from the outside and you get the type-safety.

Comment: This should be an accepted answer with extra bracket per above. Here's the reference from React Docs: https://react.dev/reference/react/forwardRef